Populating java error in postman response
am working on a spring-boot project and am trying to send a custom error in postman body that will look something like this.
{
  status:404,
  message:"No Question Found."
}

In my service class I have implemented this code and I want to send the error.
if (outputDTOSet.size() != 0) {
        } else {
            throw new BusinessException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND,"No Question Found");
        }

But in the console am getting error.
[Request processing failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl] with root cause

BusinessException class
public class BusinessException extends WebApplicationException {
    public BusinessException(Response.Status status, String errorMessage){
        super(Response.status(status)
                .entity(new ErrorResponse(status.getStatusCode(), errorMessage)).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
    }
}

ErrorResponse.java class
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorResponse {
    private int status;
    private String errorMessage;
}


Please help.

I think you need an @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class) in your controller to translate the exception into a DTO. At least, that's how I've done it in the past. It can also be in a common base class rather than directly in the controller. See: ExceptionHandler

There are many errors in your code. Capturing custom exceptions in springboot should be done as follows：

Create custom exception：

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BusinessException extends RuntimeException { // I didn't find the WebApplicationException , so I replaced it with RuntimeException
    private int status;
    private String message;
}


Capture custom exceptions and return error messages

@ControllerAdvice // This annotation must be added
@Slf4j
public class BusinessExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class) // This annotation must be added
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse handleBusinessException(BusinessException e) {
        log.error("BusinessException: {}", e.getMessage());
        return new ErrorResponse(e.getStatus(), e.getMessage());
    }
}



test

@RequestMapping("/error_test")
public void error() {
    throw new BusinessException(404, "No Question Found");
}

